# How do I create a MPEG stream with private binary data using avconv?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, transport-stream

I have some binary data that I need to transmit with a MPEG transport stream. I don't need to worry about the tables, because another software in the process is going to insert them into the stream.

I have a fixed private PID that I have to use. Is there a way to just "break" this binary data into TS packets with the my private PID using only this command line tool (avconv)? If not, is it possible with the C library?